# nestjs mongoose schema with embedded objects without embedded documents

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I am creating a schema that included embedded objects (not documents). I do not need embedded documents because the embedded objects do not exist independently and I do not need associated object IDs. This is not well documented in the Nest documentation but I came up with this which is working for the most part:

```js
const pointType = {
  coordinates: { type: [Number], required: true },
  type: { type: ['Point'], required: true },
}

const locationType = {
  name: String,
  address: addressType,
  geolocation: { pointType },
}
const timedLocationType = {
  timestamp: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now() },
  geolocation: { type: pointType, required: true }, // <<---- Problem is here with the 'required' attribute
}

export class TripLocation {
  name: string
  geolocation: Point
  address?: Address
}

export class TimedLocation {
  time: Date
  geolocation: Point
}


@Schema()
export class Trip {

  @Prop({ type: locationType, required: true })
  start: TripLocation

  @Prop({ type: locationType, required: true })
  end: TripLocation

  @Prop({ type: [timedLocationType], default: [] }) // <<-- Problem is here
  route: TimedLocation[]

}
```

This works except for having the `timedLocation` array. Mongoose does not seem to like having the route property as an array. As is, the code throws this error:

```
.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:1001
    throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +
    ^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `geolocation.required`. See .../mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.
    at Schema.interpretAsType (.../node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema.js:1001:11)
```

If I remove the `required` attribute on the `timedLocationType.geolocation`, the error goes away. Alternatively, if I turn the `route property from an array to a single object, and keep the` required` attribute, the error also goes away:

```
  @Prop({ type: timedLocationType })
  route: TimedLocation
```